# Codificación de caracteres en nombre de Archivo - PHP

Tags: php, string, codificación

Al cargar un archivo lo estoy renombrando para eliminar los caracteres especiales, pero al cargar un archivo con un nombre especifico y al imprimirlo en pantalla aparentemente php no puede leerlo correctamente, para ser más claro al cargar un archivo con este nombre :

> "Boletín año 16 No.  37 Políticas Comerciales - Ventas con fines de
>   exportación - Actualización XXI"

lo que php lee al imprimir $_FILES['upload']['name'][0] es :

> "boleti?n_an?o_16_no_37_poli?ticas_comerciales.pdf"

Estuve analizando más el nombre del archivo y noté que tiene una codificación extraña, es decir la "ñ" del nombre no es la "ñ" que normalmente usamos pues si se compara ese carácter da false incluso usé la siguiente herramienta : https://text-compare.com/ y efectivamente sus caracteres son diferentes, no entiendo por qué motivo será esto, pero la cosa es que debo lograr leerlos y remplazar espacios, acentos y caracteres especiales, estoy usando lo siguiente :

```
$_FILES['upload']['name'][$i] = formatearNombre($_FILES['upload']['name'][$i]);

function formatearNombre($cadena){ 
$tofind = "ÀÁÂÃÄÅàáâãäåÒÓÔÕÖØòóôõöøÈÉÊËèéêëÇçÌÍÎÏìíîïÙÚÛÜùúûüÿÑñ· ,@"; 
$replac = "AAAAAAaaaaaaOOOOOOooooooEEEEeeeeCcIIIIiiiiUUUUuuuuyNn-___"; 
$cadena = utf8_decode($cadena);      
$cadena = strtr($cadena, utf8_decode($tofind), $replac);  
$cadena = strtolower($cadena);  
return utf8_encode($cadena); 

}
```

Comment: Por curiosidad: en qué OS y web server estás ejecutándolo?

Comment: Chequeaste que estés trabajando todo en utf8 y la salida también? [Como poner tu sitio web en utf8](http://www.phptherightway.com/#php_and_utf8 )